# Should I lag the independent variable or dependent variable to get delayed effects of the IV on DV?

Tags: r, regression, lags

I'm doing research where I am getting the delayed effects of my Xs on my Y using a 2-way fixed effects approach. Since all of my Xs will end up being delayed, should I lag my Y by -1 or should I lag all of my Xs by +1? Or does it not matter? Since I'm getting different coefficients from doing both approaches, I am also wondering what the difference is between those two theoretically. If someone could explain to me how they would be different, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In the simple example below using R we get the exact same coefficients whether we lag the RHS or reverse lag the LHS so more details are needed to understand why you are getting different results.  Note that the base R `lag` function does not work on plain vectors so we used `flag` from the collapse package.  Also `BOD` is a data frame that comes with R (shown in the Note at the end.)

```
library(collapse)

lm(demand ~ flag(Time), BOD)
## Call:
## lm(formula = demand ~ flag(Time), data = BOD)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)   flag(Time)  
##       11.46         1.56  

lm(flag(demand, -1) ~ Time, BOD)
## Call:
## lm(formula = flag(demand, -1) ~ Time, data = BOD)
##
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)         Time  
##       11.46         1.56
```

### Note

```
> BOD
  Time demand
1    1    8.3
2    2   10.3
3    3   19.0
4    4   16.0
5    5   15.6
6    7   19.8
```